# Excel - Using a macro to get information from every 100th cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets. Sheet 1 and Sheet 2.
Sheet 1 contains names, followed by other data, input by a user.
Sheet 2 then needs to list those names typed into Sheet 1.

I know the names are every 100 cells, eg. A1, A101, A201.
I can get the names from Sheet 1 in to Sheet 2 with the code:

```
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula= "=Sheet1!A1"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

My question is, if I have 100 names I need to get from Sheet 1, is it possible make a loop and offset the formula reference cell by 100 each time? So the first time it gets cell A1, then A101, and so on.

This is the loop I would normally use, but I dont know how to change the reference cell each time. I dont know if you can alter strings in such a way so that it will be A1, then A101, then 102 etc...

```
Dim x As Long
For x = 1 To 100
    ActiveCell.Formula= "=Sheet1!A1"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next x
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: _then A101, then 102 etc_ ?? Do you mean 201 . `ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sheet1!A" & x * 100 - 99`

Comment: another way, if no loop it's OK with you  : `with sheets(2).range("a1:a100"): .value = "=indirect(""sheet1!A""&row()*100-99)": .value = .value: end with`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many names are there? I'll assume there are 50, just change `For x = 1 to ???` below, replacing ??? with the number of names times 100.

```
Dim x As Long
For x = 1 To 5000 Step 100
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sheet1!A" & x
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next x
```

Comment: Thats brilliant. thank you so much! Saved me a lot of time!